# error message displaying, giving problems with user login Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Having a problem, in terms of creating my signup to post and go through. It is throwing my error messages username is already taken and email is already taken, when neither is true, even when I enter in brand new sets of information. Anybody think they can help solve?

**Forms.py:**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'required':True}))
    username=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username','required':True}))
    password=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password','required':True}))
    password2=forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Enter Password','required':True}))


    class Meta:
        """ To Specify the fields from User model from django, and to prevent abstraction"""
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']

    def clean_username(self):
        users = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if not users:
            return self.cleaned_data["username"]
        raise forms.ValidationError("This username already exist")

    def clean_email(self):
        emails = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if not emails:
            return self.cleaned_data["email"]
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email is already registered")

    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if not password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")

        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")

        return password2
```

**views.py:**

```
def signup(request):
    template_var={}
    form=SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("register")
    template_var["form"]=form
    return    render_to_response("registration/signup.html",template_var,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `clean_username(self)`, why do you only return `self.cleaned_data["username"]` if it is empty (the case where `not users == True`)? And you don't actually check for duplicate user names.

The function should look like this:

```
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    if not username:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter a username.")
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).count() > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This username already exists.")
    return username
```

Your email check has the same bugs.

Comment: I see the check you made! makes sense. So within my views.py I received an error message stating the SignupForm in the forms.py has no attribute login "user = form.login(request) in my views.py" So would I have to sub out in my views.py the attribute .login() with the function definitions I have over in my forms.py under the SignupForm class?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing all your code. All I can do is point you to the Django login stuff: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/